# Embed IP Camera streaming into website with PHP?

Tags: php, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have done a quick google on this but i was wondering if this is possible? I have opened up ports on our router to it so its accessible from anywhere but could i use PHP or similar to grab live streaming and show it on a website somewhere?

Comment: What format dows the stream have?

Comment: MPEG-4, is that what you were after?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page/23392116#23392116

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (HTML5) or just the inner object (HTML<5) with all occurences of `%StreamURL%` replaced with the URL of your stream.

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls>
    <source src="%StreamURL%" type="video/mp4">
    <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "%StreamURL%", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true}}' /> 
        <p><a href="%StreamURL%">view with external app</a></p> 
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: thanks for this, didnt work so went with iFrames but oh well!

Comment: What would the `%StreamURL%` be if I want to stream the server's webcam and not myself?

Comment: this code is working if streamurl in LAN. how is it in WAN?

Answer (score 4):

You need a server to broadcast the stream for the viewers and player component that can work on desktop and mobile as well.

I have posted some info about this here on another stackowerflow topic:
[How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page/23392116#23392116)

More info: http://ipcamlive.com/howdoesitwork

Comment: can you please guide me how can we stream virtual camera to video conferencing room (webrtc) I am using direct show plugin