# Best way to put video from RTSP to HTML page?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, vlc

I have a url to RTSP stream with authentication in H264 - MPEG-4 part 10 codec.
Lik looks like this: rtsp://login:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:557

Is there way to show video in HTML-page?

Is it require to use some decoding server like ffmpeg or vlc?
Or we can put it to page directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be put directly as link. It will use your default player to play it and not on the webpage itself. Example page: http://bcdn1.wpc.cdn.bigcdn.com/001D7A/bcdn2/bbb-rtsp.html

```
<body>

<div id="rtsp_movie">

    <a href="rtsp://xxxx"><img border="0"
                           alt="EXAMPE RTSP"
                           width="426"
                           height="240"/>click
    to play RTSP</a>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Directly link doesn't work rtsp://login:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:557

Comment: What message do you get? Does this link play with vlc or quicktime player? I have a working page where I link the rtsp video directly.

Comment: Browsers doesn't known what is rtsp://
Quicktime doenst support this link(IMHO) format and doesn't play.
VLC works fine

Comment: In Quicktime Version 10.1 (501.22), you can use open location to play the stream. http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/ mentions quicktime can play it.

Comment: @Max Can you play the video in the link above?

Comment: sorry, but i can't find links to video in your link (

Comment: Do you see the `click to play RTSP` in http://bcdn1.wpc.cdn.bigcdn.com/001D7A/bcdn2/bbb-rtsp.html . What happens when you click on it?

Comment: I see. You link works fine6 but my link require login/pass and doesn't work in QuickTime

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23202/discussion-between-max-and-d33pika)

Comment: You may want to check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page)