# How to play/stream RTSP via web.

Tags: html, rtsp

Can someone guide me on how to properly stream an RSTP in web?

So I have this url `rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/vid/stream/channels/1`
When played via VLC player Streaming in my desktop appears to run/stream fine.

My next challenge is, to view this via WEB. So I created a simple HTML site, and embedded the quicktime code which I found somewhere in stackoverflow.

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"  WIDTH="400" HEIGHT="300" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab";>
<PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/vid/stream/channels/1";>
<PARAM NAME="controller" VALUE="false">
<PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="qtsrc" VALUE="rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/vid/stream/channels/1";>
<PARAM NAME="pluginspage" VALUE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/indext.html";>
<PARAM name="type" VALUE="video/quicktime">
<EMBED WIDTH="400" HEIGHT="300" AUTOPLAY="true" CONTROLLER="false" SRC="rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/vid/stream/channels/1"; qtsrc="rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/vid/stream/channels/1"; BGCOLOR="FFFFFF" BORDER="0" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/indext.html";></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

i also included these on my `<head>` tag

```
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/ac_quicktime.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/qtp_library.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/stylesheets/qtp_library.css" rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" />
```

But when I load the page, I get a blank screen.

I have tried chrome/ie/firefox.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page)

Answer (score -2):

You have to redirect your router public port 554 to the private 192.168.1.55:554 port in order to access it form other location in the web.

finally you need to change the code:

rtsp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:554/vid/stream/channels/1

instead of

rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/vid/stream/channels/1

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the public ip of your router