# Stream rtsp url in Windows Media Player 12

Tags: rtsp, windows-media-player

I have created a live streaming server using rtsp protocol on my machine with link of media as
`rtsp://192.168.xx.xx/livedata.sdp`
When I pass the link on another machine connected in network to VLC player streaming works fine.
But when I pass the same link to Windows Media Player I get following error:-

"Windows Media Player cannot play the file because the specified protocol is not supported. If you typed a URL in the Open URL dialog box, try using a different transport protocol (for example, "http:" or "rtsp:")."

I have searched on net for the said error and tried all kind of stuff like registering wmnetmgr.dll and checking for permissions of WMSDKNS.XML but nothing worked.I have also checked the settings in Tools->Options->Network Tab and ticked all the check boxes i.e.
RTSP/TCP, RTSP/UDP, HTTP.

I am using Windows Media Player 12.0.7600.16385.

I am attaching the screenshot of the error below.
Please provide me with a solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: WMP does not support RTSP feeds. Your solution is to find a third party component, Media Foundation or DirectShow, to extend WMP appropriately.

Comment: Can you specify to me any third party component?

Comment: Is there any way to achieve rtsp streaming in windows form application? Earlier I was doing http streaming in my application using wmp and media element which worked fine. I wanted an option for RTSP streaming.

Comment: You are looking for some kind of magic. You can of course find non-WMP solution. With WMP however, you need to first resolve the question of WMP's support for RTSP, which does not exist out of the box.

Comment: try VLC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page