# How to run rtsp video on web page

Tags: javascript, rtsp

Hey I would like to know if I can stream an rtsp video on a web page.

If so which third party library can do this work, or what are the available solutions in this current state.

I know that I can run rtsp video on vlc, but can I run vlc on a web page?

I will be glad for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link may help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video

Comment: Take a look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page#6610007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [web plugin from VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin). From the documentation:

To embed the plugin into a webpage, use the following  template:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
  width="100" height="100" target="rtsp://yourip" />
```

If you are using vlc version < 2.2.0 with Internet Explorer, use instead the following `<object>` template:

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
  width="100" height="100" target="rtsp://yourip" ></object>
```

For the declaration of tag attributes, use the tag . Here an example:

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
  width="100" height="100" target="rtsp://yourip" >
    <param name="autostart" value="true" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" />
</object>
```

For compatibility with the mozilla plugin, you can combine both tags:

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc">
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" name="vlc" />
</object>
```

Comment: I have add the following embeded code but I get that this plugin isn't supported, can you tell me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: no way to overcome it. VLC plugin is a rather rare used thing and more for developers.  Use some server like flussonic or ffmpeg + nginx to repack rtsp transport to something like hls or dash.

Comment: "Support for NPAPI plugins was removed from all modern web browsers, so VLC's plugin is no longer maintained".