# RTSP link doesn't open in Google Chrome

Tags: html

I created a simple HTML page with a link to an RTSP stream. However, when I open the page in Google Chrome, and click the RTSP link, nothing happens. No errors are emitted in the F12 Chrome Dev Tools either.

I would expect that clicking the link would invoke an external program to open the link. I have VLC on Windows 10 selected as the "default app" for video playback.

```
<a href="rtsp://hostname/path">Video Feed</a>
```

When I open the same link in Firefox, I receive the following error:

[image]

> The address wasn’t understood
>   Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (rtsp) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.
>       You might need to install other software to open this address.

**Question**: How can I get an RTSP link to prompt me to open an RTSP stream with a video player installed locally, in Google Chrome on Windows 10?

Comment: Why the Firefox screenshot and error when your title and question are asking about Chrome?

Comment: have a look here maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598475/stream-rtsp-to-html-website

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the link. I have already explored that option. However at this point, I'm not trying to embed the stream in the page, but rather open the link with an external program (ie. VLC).

Comment: @j08691 to show that I tried an alternative option, instead of just giving up on Chrome.