# An html page (and player) to play RTSP video play back

Tags: html, rtsp, rtsp-client

I want to run the `RTSP` live video stream on my web page.The following code works good with the rtsp//url as shown in the code but when I replace that URL with my cam IP ,its not working.The cam IP link is playing in VLC player but not in my HTML PAGE.

[How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page)
 is some what related to what i'm trying to ask but it doen't help me to find solution.
Is there any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Streamedian player example</title>
    <style>
        #test_video {
            width: 720px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="test_video" controls autoplay>    
   <source src="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" 
     type="application/x-rtsp">       
   <!-- <source src="rtsp://admin:abc@myIPAddress/" 
          type="application/x-rtsp">-->
</video>   
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/babel-polyfill/7.0.0-beta.2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="streamedian.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var p = Streamedian.player('test_video', {socket:  "wss://specforge.com/ws/"})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```