# Re-stream RTSP from IP cam with Node Media Server to http/ws and display it with html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url, rtsp

## Goal

My goal is to display my IP cam's RTSP-output stream on a standard HTML-page (html5 + css3 + vanilla javascript, no magic = no plugins). The HTML-page should be hosted in a NGINX web server on my Raspberry Pi.

## My equipment

The setup I am using is a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Rasbian OS,  Node.js and [Node-Media-Server package](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server), NGINX (*but I do not believe that NGINX is important for my problem? I have not made any config for the Node-Media-Server in it anyway.*) An IP-camera, and a browser.
[image]

## What I have tried

The [readme](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server#readme) in the Node-Media-Server-project is detailed and there is a tutorial describing almost exactly what I want to do. Specifically, there is a markup example on how the live stream could be accessed:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Camera</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/flv.js/1.4.0/flv.min.js"></script>
    <video id="videoElement"></video>
    <script>
        if (flvjs.isSupported()) {
            var videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');
            var flvPlayer = flvjs.createPlayer({
                type: 'flv',
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/live/uterum.flv'
            });
            flvPlayer.attachMediaElement(videoElement);
            flvPlayer.load();
            flvPlayer.play();
        }
    </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

This is how I start the media server on my Raspberry PI, `kommandoran-mediaserver.js`:

```
const { NodeMediaServer } = require('node-media-server');

const config = {
    logType: 3, // 3 - Log everything (debug)
    rtmp: {
        port: 1935,
        chunk_size: 60000,
        gop_cache: true,
        ping: 60,
        ping_timeout: 30
    },
    http: {
        port: 8000,
        allow_origin: '*'
    },
    relay: {
        ffmpeg: '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
        tasks: [
            {
                app: 'cctv',
                mode: 'static',
                edge: 'rtsp://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@10.0.0.111/live1.sdp',
                name: 'uterum',
                rtsp_transport : 'tcp' //['udp', 'tcp', 'udp_multicast', 'http']
            }
        ]
    }
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config)
nms.run();
```

## My problem and question

When I try to view `camera.html` (see markup above) via the Chromium browser on Raspberry Pi (i.e. local host), nothing is displayed. In the Chromium debug inspector there are no javascript errors, but I get this:
`GET http://localhost:8000/live/uterum.flv net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Here is a screenshot from the node terminal:
[image]
The red area illustrates the output when I try to make a request to `http://localhost:8000/live/uterum.flv`.

I suppose I try to reach the wrong endpoint but which is correct? The documentation states `http://localhost:8000/live/STREAM_NAME.flv`. What is "`STREAM_NAME`" in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the configuration, your RTSP stream is pushed to the ‘cctv’ application.

So your playback address should be:

```
rtmp://localhost/cctv/uterum
```

or

```
http://localhost:8000/cctv/uterum.flv
```