# I need show "rtsp//:" live streaming on react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am studying face detection system, but I have a problem, and I need help. I've read and tried many pictures from the internet, but I still can't.
I want to display "rtsp //:" live streaming on a response by nodejs.

My URL:

`rtsp://username:password@IP:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0`

I have a username and password. But I can't show the stream on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying RTSP in a browser directly is generally not supported - there are and have been many workarounds over the years and you can see some of then history in answers like this:[How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2245040/334402)

I think you may find it easier to convert the RTSP into another format - WebRTP is an obvious choice given its widespread support now and the fact that is realtime (priorities latency over video quality), unlike many popular video streaming protocols (prioritise video quality over latency).

There are some open source solutions that can help - this one appears well used and has recent activity:

- https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC