# How to display RTSP stream from IPCamera in webapp

Tags: http-live-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm looking for a way to display multiple camerastreams (up to 200 cameras) in a single web application (only a single stream will be visible at each time).

My initial plan was to connect the webapp to the cameras by using an rtsp stream, but this protocol is not supported by most browsers. I have found some sources that it should be possible to display using a thirdparty plugin but for now no luck.

Another idea I had was to deploy a kubernetes cluster with a transcoding service for each camera that converts a rtsp stream into an HLS stream, which is usable in a webapp. But this means defining a hard link between each transcoder pod and each camera.

So my question: Is there an easy way of using rtsp streams in a webapp? Or what do you guys think is a viable way to handle this many cameras in a webapp?

So many thanks!

Comment: Look Info golang rtsptowebrtc Project just Google it ;)

Comment: Please look at *[How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2245040/192373)*

Comment: Yeah, found those, didn't work ;)

Comment: You need to restream rtsp to hls, or into WebRTC. FastoCloud can do it from box.