# Video chat using html5 javascript hibernate

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a chat client which is presently working on `javascript, html5 and java (Hibernate)`.  I am planning to add video chat over it.  I do not want to add `flash`, so the only way to obtain webcam access, to my knowledge, was to use `HTML5` other than `silverlight` (not so great reviews) and `applet`.  The problem is how do I send the video stream of one chat user to the server and back to the other chat user who is on the other side of the chat.  I have searched and found out that `RTSP` is not going to be implemented in `Chrome`.  So do I use `HTTP` for this? If so, could you provide me with some guidelines. If not what are my other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006037/can-html-5-serve-real-time-media-stream