# Can you recommend a solution to convert real time stream from pc camera to the format of rtp/rtsp?

Tags: camera, rtp

I just walked through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5), and found html5 video is fantastic.

So now what I need to do is convert video streams from pc camera into `rtp/rtsp` format.

Is there a good solution you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

[vlc](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html#id517423) and [ffserver](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver-doc.html) both can do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to publish camera stream to the vlc or ffserver?

Comment: Well, if you follow the vlc link and use the example command line (swap `input_stream` for the path to your pc camera) you should be able to simply put `src="rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp"` in the html5 video tag.

Comment: No, it's impossible to ask the user to specify that `input_stream` which they don't understand,I'm trying to achieve something like this site provides: http://www.mobileipcamviewer.com/

Comment: for windows it's something like `dshow://`. linux, something like `v4l:///dev/video`. There is plenty more info on the VLC wiki. http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Stream_from_Encoding_Cards_and_Other_Capture_Devices#Under_GNU.2FLinux

Comment: you run vlc on the *server*. the camera is attached to the server, right? The product on the site you linked only works with *IP* cameras.

Comment: VLC is on the server, but the camera is on the client.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question with a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve. mobileipcamviewer.com and "camera is on the client" are not the same thing.

Comment: this is a programming website, if entering a commandline is too difficult then you're asking for a boxed GUI solution (that's VLC). At any rate if the camera is on a web client then it's surely at the bad end of a DSL line or 3G and streaming upstream on a consumer connection is generally unworkable. You should do more research or explain your problem better.