# Android RTSP Using Video-View

Tags: android

I am developing an application which consists of video-player.

- I have got sample And it was working fine for me.
- I have pasted the `http://` link instead of `rtsp` link it's not working.

My problem is how to convert the `http` link to `rtsp` Link?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exact, neither i know if this will work, because I did not had much success, but there are certain solutions that can convert streams, go through following links, see if it helps.:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/video-encoding/14320/how-to-convert-wmv-to-mp4-in-real-time

[Can you recommend a solution to convert real time stream from pc camera to the format of rtp/rtsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014716/can-you-recommend-a-solution-to-convert-real-time-stream-from-pc-camera-to-the-f)

[RTSP to RTMP streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010019/rtsp-to-rtmp-streaming)

http://real7ime-converter.en.softonic.com/

Any software that can inter convert various other stream formats , will be able to convert http to rtsp also.....

See if it helps.......