# HTML 5 Video Tag

Tags: video, html

This is my first dip into HTML5, firstly is there a special way to open the html tag? I read a stack overflow question, which seemed to result in the fact that an rtsp could be srced in a video tag.

[Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)

So I have attempted to do so! I have the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<video src="rtsp://urlexample/sample_h264_1mbit.mp4">No HTML5 support</video>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I open this script in chrome and nothing appears, nothing loads, not even No HTML5 support shows up! I have looked into using cvlc to capture and then display a stream, but I was hoping that this new technology could be utilized to display the video. Any advice would be of help! Thank you.

Comment: Due to such a large variety of supporting browsers and non supporting browsers, I decided to use javascript to stream the video, an excellent tutorial can be found here, by the way thanks for your input guys,

http://soundscreen.com/streaming/embed_streams.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Chrome supports rtsp at this time: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25573

Have you tried it in Safari with quicktime installed?  I think Safari does support rtsp, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have read that Safari supports rtp streams inside the video tag, but I know one thing for sure, It doesn't load an rtsp src in any browser in this tag, I had to use Javascript to load it unfortunately. I'm not sure what the difference is between rtp and rtsp, perhaps they are the same! lol but I tried an rtp protocol with this stream to no avail, thanks for your input dar.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to be aware of is that the contents inside of the  tag only show up if the browser doesn't support the HTML5  tag.  This is important, because it means if your browser has support for it but just doesn't understand the codec or can't load the video for some reason, that text will *not* be displayed.

If you want to look at some more examples, this doc from Apple has a bunch of working examples that might help you get started.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html