# Website Help - Creating a better ChatRoulette

Tags: html, css, video, video-streaming

I know html and css, and a little mysql and php. I want to make a site similar to chatroulette.

What languages and technologies do you recommend I learn and use? And could you please describe the best way to faciliate the video chat aspect of the site?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look on Flash..!

Comment: i hate flash...but this is still the correct answer. if you want video, go flash. or... maybe html5 that degrades to flash. can html5 video do streaming content or no?

Comment: I believe html5 can do streaming through the <video> tag. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5