# FFmpeg RTP streaming error

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, live, rtp

I want to broadcast a video file via FFmpeg, but I get this error:

> Only one stream supported in the RTP muxer

I get that error when I write this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i SomeVideo.mp4 -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11111
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: How many streams are in `SomeVideo.mp4`?

Comment: Only One.But I can't start streaming ((

Comment: @Will why did you close ??? Please reopen or tell the reason.

Comment: Because its off topic.  Running vidya streaming software is not on topic.  Issues encountered while creating one is.  [faq]

Comment: @will , OK I understood. Maybe you move this question to SuperUser ? There are a lot of ffmpeg and streaming questions in SU.

Comment: @SEARAS: Asked in 12, closed in May, and now?  Anyhow, nobody can migrate after 6 months, so it would be better to ask over there.

Comment: This topic suites more to SO as superuser, as ffmpeg is a very code-dependent tool

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your ffmpeg command creates *two* streams, one for video, one for audio.
Do this instead:

`ffmpeg -re -i SomeVideo.mp4 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11111 -vn -acodec copy -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11112`

Port `11111` then has video without audio (`-an`).

Port `11112` then has audio without video (`-vn`).

Read each stream with, e.g., `ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:11112`.

(Part of this comes from advice at http://lucabe72.blogspot.com/2010/04/rtp-streaming-with-ffmpeg.html .)

### Edit 2021/08

The command should be
`ffmpeg -re -i SomeVideo.mp4 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11111 -vn -acodec copy -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11113`

- 11111 => video RTP
- 11112 => video RTCP implicitly
- 11113 => audio RTP
- 11114 => audio RTCP implicitly

Because RTCP port will be set to the RTP port + 1 automatically, or you’d get the bind failed error while playing.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtp

Comment: Is that possible to multiple output over RTP? even with removing audio stream, It show error: Only one stream supported in the RTP muxer - Could not write header for output file #1 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Comment: Yes, but only through multicast.  RFC 1889 says "RTP supports data transfer to multiple destinations using multicast distribution if provided by the underlying network," and says nothing else about multiple clients.  See http://superuser.com/questions/307130/ffmpeg-command-to-stream-video-to-a-multicast-address .

Comment: I had to use 11110 (ie an even number) for the video, else `ffplay` would show errors and `vlc` would only read the audio. The VLC wiki https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/#rtp states `This port has to be even.` for both audio and video.

Comment: If I am doing a live stream of my desktop on one RTP flux and an other for the audio, how could I get, client side, video + audio with rtp ? Is RTP a good choice for that ?