# Stream webcam via. Wowza streaming server

Tags: php, actionscript, webcam, live-streaming, wowza

I am trying to make a site where user can stream their webcams via Wowza server. I have no idea from where to start off. I am using PHP.

How to send the webcam stream from client to wowza server. What should I use to send stream from the client, is it possible though HTML 5 video or should I use Adobe flash player Actionscript?

A bit help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to Stack Owerflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623912/streaming-live-video-in-html-5

Comment: Hello, I checked it out, but its not answering my main question i.e. How do i send my webcam stream from a client's system to Wowza server?? Can you help me out on this??

Comment: actually this is could be tuff one.  I do not know yet, havent had time to dig this field, thou, I would rather manage streaming software ON the clients system, than using some service. Find a code or write yours.

Answer (score 2):

Your clients will need to use Flash Live Media Encoder, Wirecast, XSplit, vMix, OBS or some other Encoding software package. HTML5 doesn't, itself, stream using RTMP.

Here's a discussion on this very topic at [Wowza Support](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?16287-Recording-Webcam-to-Wowza).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is why putting just a link to an answer is not a good answer. The link is not working, and the other information in the answer doesn't help much either.