# HTML5 live streaming

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

For school I need to set up an HTML5 live stream site. They have a flash stream-player they've been using but now they want it to use HTML5 instead. How can I do this? I tried using the video tag but I can't get it working. Below is the code I have. Could someone point me in the correct direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Deltion Live Streaming</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../swfobject.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  

    <video id="movie" width="460" height="306" preload autoplay>
        <source src="rtmp://fl2.sz.xlcdn.com:80/sz=Deltion_College=lb1"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
            <!-- HERE THE CODE FOR THE ALTERNATIVE PLAYER (FLASH) WILL BE! -->
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: similar for RTSP (open RTMP successor) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5

Comment: more constrained question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client

Answer (score 28):

A possible alternative for that:

1. Use an encoder (e.g. VLC or FFmpeg) into packetize your input stream
   to OGG format. For example, in this case I used VLC to packetize
   screen capture device with this code:

   > C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe -I dummy screen://
   >   :screen-fps=16.000000 :screen-caching=100
   >   :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,width=600,height=480,acodec=mp3}:http{mux=ogg,dst=127.0.0.1:8080/desktop.ogg}
   >   :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
2. Embed this code into a `<video>` tag in your HTML page like that:

   `<video id="video" src="http://localhost:8080/desktop.ogg" autoplay="autoplay" />`

This should do the trick. However it's kind of poor performance and AFAIK MP4 container type should have a better support among browsers than OGG.

Comment: Works fine from any PC. But I cannot get it to work on mobile (eg from Chrome on Android). Any idea?

Comment: @AdorjanPrincz This is probably due to lack of ogg decoder on Android/Chrome. Try different video (and/or container) formats.

Comment: @AdorjanPrincz what is the latency of this? below 1 second?

Answer (score 25):

Live streaming in HTML5 is possible via the use of Media Source Extensions (MSE) - the relatively new W3C standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/
MSE is an an extension of HTML5 `<video>` tag; the javascript on webpage can fetch audio/video segments from the server and push them to MSE for playback. The fetching mechanism can be done via HTTP requests (MPEG-DASH) or via WebSockets. As of September 2016 all major browsers on all devices support MSE. iOS is the only exception.

For high latency (5+ seconds) HTML5 live video streaming you can consider MPEG-DASH implementations by video.js or Wowza streaming engine.

For low latency, near real-time HTML5 live video streaming, take a look at EvoStream media server, Unreal media server, and WebRTC.

Answer (score 21):

Firstly you need to setup a media streaming server. You can use Wowza, red5 or [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). Read their documentation and setup on OS you want.
All the engine are support HLS (Http Live Stream protocol that was developed by Apple). You should read documentation for config.
Example with nginx-rtmp-module:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
} 

server {
    listen 8080;

    location /hls {
        # Disable cache
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /mnt/;
    }
}
```

After server was setup and configuration successful. you must use some rtmp encoder software (OBS, wirecast ...) for start streaming like youtube or twitchtv.

In client side (browser in your case) you can use [Videojs](http://videojs.com/) or JWplayer to play video for end user. You can do something like below for Videojs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Streaming</title>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="360" width="640" controls preload="none">
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/hls/stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
<script>
    var player = videojs('#player');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You don't need to add others plugin like flash (because we use HLS not rtmp). This player can work well cross browser with out flash.

Comment: Your configuration file seems to miss the http block for the server part. But is generally finding it hard to get this streaming business working.

Comment: In the HTML section, you invoke stream.m3u8, I don't see that name in the server configuration, where did you get it?

Answer (score 17):

Right now it will only work in some browsers,
and as far as I can see you haven't actually linked to a file,
so that would explain why it is not playing.

but as you want a live stream (which I have not tested with)

check out [Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)

and http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/25-HTML5-Video-Resources-You-Might-Have-Missed-74010.aspx

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to use the RTMP protocol in HTML 5, because the RTMP protocol is only used between the server and the **flash** player. So you can use the other streaming protocols for viewing the streaming videos in HTML 5.

Comment: what is other protocols?

Comment: @eri HLS for example

Answer (score 5):

You can use a fantastic library name [Videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js). You will find more useful informations here. But with quick start you can do something like this:

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video.min.js"></script>
<video id="Video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="auto"
    height="auto" poster="poster.jpg"
    data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash", "html5", "other supported tech"], "nativeControlsForTouch": true, "controlBar": { "muteToggle": false, "volumeControl": false, "timeDivider": false, "durationDisplay": false, "progressControl": false } }'>
        <source src="rtmp://{domain_server}/{publisher}" type='rtmp/mp4' />
</video>
<script>
    var player = videojs('Video');
    player.play();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ffmpeg + ffserver. It works!!!
You can get a config file for ffserver from ffmpeg.org and accordingly set the values.

Comment: Please post your commands and configs, I'm having a bit of problems.

Answer (score -12):

```
<object classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
            height="285" id="mediaPlayer" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
            type="application/x-oleobject" width="360" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <param name="fileName" value="mms://my_IP_Address:my_port" />
            <param name="animationatStart" value="true" />
            <param name="transparentatStart" value="true" />
            <param name="autoStart" value="true" />
            <param name="showControls" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <embed autosize="-1" autostart="true" bgcolor="darkblue" designtimesp="5311" displaysize="4"
                height="285" id="mediaPlayer" loop="true" name="mediaPlayer" pluginspage="http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/"
                showcontrols="true" showdisplay="0" showstatusbar="-1" showtracker="-1" src="mms://my_IP_Address:my_port"
                type="application/x-mplayer2" videoborder3d="-1" width="360"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not useful. You would stand a better chance of helping someone (and getting upvotes) if you included a short explanation as part of every answer.

Comment: @AsongAmagin You're missing a closing tag for that object element.

Comment: Windows only, so lose all that cross-platform support that HTML 5 offers.