# Best approach to get RTSP streaming into web browser from IP Camera?

Tags: ffmpeg, websocket, activex, webbrowser-control, rtsp

Is it possible to get the RTSP Streaming data into the web browser?

**Below are some of my findings. Kindly correct me if I am wrong?**

1. Only Mac OS, and Safari supports RTSP Live Streaming.
2. HTML 5 video does not support RTSP.
3. I can use the VLC plugin, but I don't want to use that.

**Possibility of mixing ffmpeg and websocket?**

Assume my IP camera is connected with Ethernet.

In the client machine:

1. I run ffmpeg to get the data from server (ie: IP)
2. Client machine runs websocket.
3. Once ffmpeg gets the data from RTSP Server, it decodes, and generates the raw image of any format (for example: yuv).
4. Now, i have to send this image to browser through websocket.

**Question:**

1. It is the right approach ?
2. How can I get the decoded image from ffmpeg into the browser ?

I might be wrong in different places. Kindly provide input.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Here](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) is a blog entry, or tutorial if you will, that achieves something very similar.

Their setup slightly different, but this is the summary:

use `ffmpeg` to convert your input into mpeg1video:

```
ffmpeg  -i rtsp://whatever -f mpeg1video -b 800k -r 30 http://localhost:8082/yourpassword/640/480/
```

Install `node.js` with `stream-server.js` script from [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) and `ws` ws WebSocket package.

To view the stream, use the `stream-example.html` and `jsmpg.js` from the [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg). Change the WebSocket URL in `stream-example.html` to `localhost` and open it in your favorite browser.

**Update** an [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257762/real-time-streaming-to-html5-with-out-webrtc-just-using-video-tag) suggest two other working solutions, with <video> tag: with [stream-m](https://github.com/yomguy/stream-m) Java server or with `ffserver`.

Comment: Does this support audio?

Comment: In theory, it does. I would recommend the `<video>` tag ***[solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257762/real-time-streaming-to-html5-with-out-webrtc-just-using-video-tag)*** better.

Comment: I mean does it support streaming the audio of the video, just by using the video tag ? :)

Comment: Yes, `<video>`  tag supports both; but it is your responsibility to prepare the relevant stream.

Comment: I cant find the stream-server.js script, could you explain that further, currently I set a local httpserver with nodejs and install jsmpeg aswell, thanks

Comment: I made it work somehow. Now how can I look at the stream currently, the stream is at this url `http://localhost:8081/secret/640/480` but the page is still loading and I do not get any view

Comment: Changing it to localhost leads to a cross origin error, how to fix this?

Comment: ffserver is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to stream that to only a very few clients, then you could use a cgi (or in nodejs, a child_process) that directly run ffmpeg:

NodeJS example:

```
app.getExpressApp().get('/camera/feed', (req, res) => {
    // Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/q/28946904/1954789
    const child_process = require('child_process');

    res.header('content-type', 'video/webm');

    const cmd = `ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pwd@somewhere/videoSub -c:v copy -c:a copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 500k -f matroska -`.split(' ');

    var child = child_process.spawn(cmd[0], cmd.splice(1), {
        stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', process.stderr]
    });

    child.stdio[1].pipe(res);

    res.on('close', () => {
        // Kill ffmpeg if the flow is stopped by the browser
        child.kill();
    });
```

CGI should be even more easier.

In the browser, you could just

```
<video autoplay=1 poster="camera.png" ><source src="/camera/feed"></video>
```

(Use a poster because the video may take some seconds before showing up).

**Caveat:
This will launch a ffmpeg for each connection to your setup, so it does not scale at all. This should be used only for a very personal website, where connections are limited (ex: to yourself only).**

PS: the ffmpeg command may need a bit of tweaking.

Comment: I believe that these days, the best approach is to [use WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23461914/192373). I am surprised that this question of 6 years back is still relevant. I have personally worked with https://github.com/mpromonet/webrtc-streamer, and was quite happy.

Comment: I am afraid you intended to post your comment to another answer

Answer (score 2):

vlc solution:

```
cvlc -v rtsp://user:password@camera_ip_address --sout='#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodedec=none}:http{dst=:8080/webcam.ogg}'
```

Then check

http://localhost:8080/webcam.ogg

Or integrate this url to whatever webservice you want to run

If you are interested in the python api of vlc, here is an example:

```
import vlc

class WebcamStreamer:
    def __init__(self, config):
        """
        Expected rtsp url format:
        "rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.1"
        """
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.stream_name = "webcam".encode()
        self.rtsp_url = config["rtsp_url"].encode()

    def launch_webcam_stream_converter(self):
        """
        Basically here is what is done:
            cmd= ["cvlc", "-v", f"rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.16",
            f"--sout='#transcode{{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodedec=none}}:http{{dst=:8080/webcam.ogg}}'"]
            subprocess.run(cmd)
        """
        ret = vlc.libvlc_vlm_add_broadcast(
            p_instance=self.instance,
            psz_name=self.stream_name,
            psz_input=self.rtsp_url,
            psz_output=f"#transcode{{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodedec=none}}:http{{dst=:8080/webcam.ogg}}".encode(),
            i_options=0,
            ppsz_options=[],
            b_enabled=True,
            b_loop=False
        )
        assert (ret == 0)
        vlc.libvlc_vlm_play_media(self.instance, self.stream_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`scandir.php` (utilised by JS in `viewcamera.php`)

```
<?php

$folder = $_GET['name'];

$dir = "../cache/".$folder;

// Sort in descending order
$b = scandir($dir,1);

$myJSON = json_encode($b);

echo $myJSON;

?>
```

`streamcam.php` (run in `crontab`)

```
<?php

function live_view ($cameraip, $cameraname){

    echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://root:pass@".$cameraip."/ufirststream -s 1920x1080 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=5 /var/www/html/occupancy/cache/".$cameraname."/frame%04d.jpg >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

}
```

`viewcamera.php` - `$camera_name` variable is from SQL while loop where below repeats for all cameras in database. var `cameraName` if from below button data attributes...

```
<button
  style="font-size: 24px"
  class="btn2 fa fa-camera"
  id="<?php echo $image_id;?>"
  href="#<?php echo $camera_name_stripped;?>"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-backdrop="false"
  data-keyboard="false"
  data-image-id="<?php echo $image_id;?>"
  data-camera-ip="<?php echo $ip;?>"
  data-camera-name="<?php echo $camera_name;?>"
  data-camera-name-stripped="<?php echo $camera_name_stripped;?>"
>
  <i style="font-size: 24px" title="Live View"></i>
</button>

 
<img width="100%" height="auto" id="img_cam<?php echo $camera_name_stripped;?>" src="">



<script>

 var cameraName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('camera-name-stripped');

 window.livetimer<?php echo $camera_name;?> = setInterval(function() {

          <?php echo $camera_name_stripped;?> = $.ajax({
              url: 'scandir.php?name='+cameraName,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json' 
          }).done(function(result)  {
              $("#img_cam<?php echo $camera_name_stripped;?>").attr('src',"../cache/" + cameraName + "/" + result[0]);
          });

          }, 55);    

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to show a streaming in different plataforms and browsers. To make that without use of any pluggins (not sure it will works on smartphones and tablets), used a approach very similar to yours. A ffmpeg crontab task creates 3 images per second, and store into a directory. Using Jquery, an ajax call to a php read the directory and get the name of the file, to change the image  (only changing the 'src' attribute of `<img>`), every 330ms. To solve the storage problem, used other crontab task that delete the files with more than 1 minute. It´s not real streaming, but is cross browser, and solves the problem pretty well.

The ffmpeg task

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://path/to/cam" -s 320x240 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=3 cache/%04d.jpg
```

Example ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: '_read_dir.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(result) {        
        $("#img_cam").prop('src',"cache/" + result.img);            
    });
```

The storage control task

```
find /var/www/path/to/dir -mmin +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Hope can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Over the years, browsers have moved away from supporting RTSP streaming. In the future, it is unlikely that browsers will support RTSP streaming. However, there have been many new developments, especially the emergence of WebRTC.

Due to the low latency of RTSP and WebRTC, a common requirement and scenario is to use WebRTC to view RTSP streams or IP Camera streams.

In simple terms, a streaming media gateway is needed to convert the RTSP stream into a WebRTC stream for viewing in a web page. The workflow is as follows:

```
IP Camera --RTSP--> FFmpeg --RTMP--> Media Server --WebRTC--> Browser
                                    (SRS Gateway)
```

It is worth noting that IP cameras generally provide an RTSP pull stream address and do not support pushing the RTSP stream to the streaming media gateway. Therefore, we need to actively pull the IP camera stream and push it to the streaming media gateway, and finally convert it to WebRTC for playback in the browser.

The overall latency of this solution is around 200ms to 500ms, and the overall effect is good. To set up a streaming media gateway, you can use Docker for one-click deployment. Refer to [this post](https://blog.ossrs.io/easily-stream-your-rtsp-ip-camera-to-youtube-twitch-or-facebook-c078db917149) for more information.

[image: RTSP to WebRTC]

The end to end latency is 260ms in the same intranet, it works really good!