# What options are there for a IP camera to webRTC/ORTC gateway? Onvif compatible or not

Tags: webrtc, ip-camera, kurento, janus-gateway, ortc

There was some discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461914/use-an-ip-camera-with-webrtc) but not specific to my questions. You can consider this as an extension to the question asked there. Googling gives only two possible solutions: [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org) and [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/). The questions I have are:

- Are there other options, opensource or otherwise?
- Among these options, can someone share some experience based upon actual use?
- Is there a list of IP Cameras which are compatible with such gateways? Or
- What specific features must an IP camera have to be able to use such a WebRTC gateway?
- Is is correct to say that if webRTC indeed takes off, then webRTC support for IP cameras is just a matter of time, which will get incorporated in standards such as Onvif?

I do not need an application per se but just the bare minimum so that other WebRTC components can be plugged in to create an application. The issue is not just about codec conversion but about some related signalling (as distinct from the WebRTC signalling which is anyway not standardized). This is discussed nicely on Kurento [here](http://www.kurento.org/blog/interoperating-webrtc-and-ip-cameras).

I have also read about IP Camera standards, in particular Onvif. I am not looking for any compatibility with this standard which is a different issue.

I did take a look at arguably the most popular opensource software for CCTV cameras: [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) but that is a very bloated software, a full-fledged application and does not have any support for streaming camera video/audio over webRTC.

Answer (score 0):

Kurento has been reported to work well with RTSP camera feeds in many occasions. You can check the [official mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kurento/ip$20camera) for that. There's a demo [here](https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc), if you are interested on how it would be done. There's a pull-request that you'll need to include, and though it could be outdated, the demo works just fine still, for letting you know how to do that.

Disclaimer: I'm part of the Kurento project.