# Access remotely webcam with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I want to monitor a remote web cam with WebRTC . I don't know where to enter the network URL (rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp) or (rtsp://IP:PORT) to remotely access the camera. Or how could I do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23473256/6235057

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use an IP-camera with webRTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461914/use-an-ip-camera-with-webrtc)