# IP CAM in Combination with UV4L and Janus-Gateway (WebRTC)

Tags: webrtc, ip-camera, janus-gateway

I am employing the use of UV4L with my IP CAM to create a virtual video driver /dev/video1. I am able to get into the API of the UV4L streaming server which has Multiple applications like JITSI, WEBRTC, JANUS etc. I noticed when I try to stream to Janus Video room on a local area connection (LAN) i.e. on my local server I get this message in the terminal

**"[6889886769210913] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlled)

   [6889886769210913] The DTLS handshake has been completed

 WebRTC media is now available"**

But no media/video stream shows up. I enabled Data channels while compiling Janus, and I also did a webrtc test with my UV4L streaming server which worked fine. But the message with Janus and why the stream doesn't show up in either Chrome or Firefox is what I need help with.

**Edit Update to answer a comment:**

The link between both is that the uv4l renders my IP cam as virtual device driver, I am using mjpeg driver module. I can then pass different options to the uv4l driver while loading it, for example I use an h264 profile stream from the IP Cam, and I also change it to mjpeg stream as well too. The funny thing is that with the h264 stream, I can run webrtc stream tests on the virtual driver created, even on Janus looking at the debug files, everything seems to work the way its supposed to, after a hangup I get the correct logs e.g

```
{
   "janus": "hangup",
   "session_id": 8829409609870864,
   "sender": 5037748733677649,
   "reason": "RTCP BYE"
}
```

My feeds goes over the wire properly tracing with Wireshark just as the successful Webrtc stream tests are displayed over the wire, my packet headers and feeds come out fine as such               :

```
[5037748733677649]  Got an RTCP packet (bundled stream)!
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017] [5037748733677649] Incoming RTCP, bundling: this is video (remote SSRC: video=2524945001, audio=65486109, got 2524945001)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]    Parsing compound packet (total of 56 bytes)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]      #1 SR (200)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]        RTCP PT 200, length: 28 bytes
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]      #2 SDES (202)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]        RTCP PT 202, length: 28 bytes
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]   End of compound packet
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017] [5037748733677649]  Got an RTCP packet (bundled stream)!
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017] [5037748733677649] Incoming RTCP, bundling: this is audio (remote SSRC: video=2524945001, audio=65486109, got 65486109)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]    Parsing compound packet (total of 56 bytes)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]      #1 SR (200)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]        RTCP PT 200, length: 28 bytes
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]      #2 SDES (202)
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]        RTCP PT 202, length: 28 bytes
[Tue Sep 26 14:28:25 2017]   End of compound packet
```

I am thinking the reason why I get no stream is because I am not testing it on an encrypted layer over the browser, i.e am not using HTTPS instead HTTP, or my host windows machine is blocking my guest Linux webrtc stream. These are the areas I tend to investigate upon, I also tried with local host, same result no stream shown, its kind of a complex policy issue for me to create a self signed cert on my VM because of privacy restrictions. I would look further and if I find no alternative I'd create a self signed license on a stanadlone machine to test it. Do you think the ssl issue might be the cause?
Update: Same thing with ssl.

Comment: Janus-gateway does not transcode the video, then the h264 profile should be set to one supported by the web browser. Did you try to set profile to baseline profile ?

Comment: Yes I set my camera profile stream to baseline, but I did not set up any h264 profiles in Janus, because I gave the uv4l driver an instance of my IP camera already to create the /dev/video1. But if there is a specific config I need to do in Janus am all ears . Thanks! @mpromonet

Comment: or how did you mean the h264 profile? @mpromonet

Comment: uv4l driver for raspicam accept '-profile baseline' to specify the h264 profile. But maybe you are using an other driver. What is the link between the IP camera and uv4l ?

Comment: @mpromonet I answered your question in the answer box below as it was to long to input as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @mpromonet I was told to add the response as an edit to the original question which I did. Thanks!

Comment: @mpromonet please can you decipher anything from the logs I posted if my setup is as its supposed to be?

Comment: Are the SDPs (local/remote) provided using H264? You can print them out in their respective handlers in the browser.

Comment: yes they are provided using H264 baseline profile, I also switch it up and change the camera stream to MJPEG but still same results, the issue is that its not even hitting my browser on my virtual machine, once I press start stream it starts but there is no pop window or stream shown, I am doing all this over a LAN connection I don't know if that would be an issue with Janus. @BenjaminTrent Thank you!

Comment: Hello, have you ever succeeded to view the stream in a browser?

Comment: @Daniel yes i did. If you need any help let me know

Comment: I've created a detailed issue here. Can you help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090325/h264-video-source-is-not-playing-in-any-browser?noredirect=1#comment87197102_50090325 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone might want to try this implementation there are are few things to take into account when configuring the described setup on a Local server, the most important being able to set up a proxy for Janus for the front end web-server (Apache or nginx) and configure the HTML scripts if you choose to use the demos for Janus(i.e streaming.html, text-room, Video-room etc), its also important to note that if you didn't install a renderer for UV4L, the web page demo for UV4L only publishes the stream but you would have to create a canvas to view the stream or use one of the available demo rooms on a web browser(google-chrome or chromium in my instance) as described above.

Comment: Go edit your question and include this information; then delete this answer.  The answer will almost certainly get deleted as not-an-answer.