# H264 video source is not playing in any browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, h.264, janus-gateway

I'm using [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/index.html) to pass video stream from an RTSP/H.264 camera ([QD800](http://www.escam.cn/product/showproduct.php?lang=en&id=77)) through WebRTC to browsers.

Which browsers am I speaking here?
Here are the details:

- Firefox (Linux, 64-bit, version 59.0.2)
- Firefox (Windows7, 64-bit, version 59.0.2)
- Chrome (Linux, 64-bit, version 49.0.2623.87)
- Chrome (Windows7, 64-bit, version 66.0.3359.139)

Originally the camera sends 420029 as profile-level-id in the SDP when negotiating with the client (Janus).

However as such Firefox is not able to play this version (420029 means level 4.1, FF is only able to play a 3.1 in theory but both are Constrained Baseline Profile).

Now my Janus streaming plugin configuration looks like this:

```
[rtsp-test]
type = rtsp
id = 4
description = RTSP
url = rtsp://admin:admin@a.b.c.d:554/11

audio = no
video = yes
videopt = 96

videortpmap = H264/90000
videofmtp = profile-level-id=42e01f\;packetization-mode=1\;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AKpWoHgCJ+VA=,aO48gA==
secret = adminpwd
```

As you can see, it's overriding the profile-level-id in the videofmtp config.

This is working fine, I can check the new profile-level-id in the WebRTC console both in FF and Chrome on both OSes.

I'm using the default demo HTML which is provided for Janus (demos/streamingtest.html).

**In neither browser is there any video displayed.
Only white box is displayed.**

When I hit play:

- in Chrome: "Stream Started 405 kbits/sec". White video screen, spinner is spinning.
- in Firefox: "Stream Started 0x0 407 kbits/sec". White video screen, no spinner, no video.

PS1.: My camera is working, VLC can play the RTSP stream directly from it.

PS2.: Both FF and Chrome are actually receiving the stream but can not decode it.

PS3.: I also tried to pass the whole RTSP through an FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://ip-camera' -an -codec copy -f rtp 'rtp://127.0.0.1:20000'
```

And then use the RTP sample of Janus, but I got the same result as above. See [FFMPEG's output](https://pastebin.com/auGKGhHf).

In the Janus helpgroup I've gone as far as possible since the stream goes through Janus, it's not their competence any more.

References:

- [Janus Groups Thread1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meetecho-janus/jKg5u9421kM)
- [Janus Groups Thread2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meetecho-janus/7HH8_blUjQo/H5DTGQPMAwAJ;context-place=topic/meetecho-janus/jKg5u9421kM)

Comment: Perhaps the format is not suitable? Can you post the output of ffmpeg? You might want try with ffplay instead and see the error.

Comment: I cannot do ffplay, because it's a headless server. FFMPEG output will is attached.

Comment: I would direct you to a post where you can complete your task, its probably due to you not setting up your html streaming page properly in your webservers

Comment: check out this page https://planb.nicecupoftea.org/2015/10/17/hackspace-hat-quick-install-or-audio-and-video-streaming-from-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-remote-or-local-webrtc-compatible-browser/

Comment: also It looks like janus has to be configured and built for data-channels

Comment: last thing I would direct you to is to make sure you setup a proxy for janus as "/janus" in whatever web server you employ apache or ngnix pointing to your webservice  complete url,  that way you can forward calls from /janus to your webpage. The gateway is configured to see /janus

Comment: The proxy would be setup wherever you have your domain name web server configuration, if you don't have a custom domain setup using the default web server config file is fine, also make sure you are using a secure page "https" to view stream from janus, most web browsers have blocked video on port 80 by default, so try to use 7443 to eliminate  unknown errors.

Comment: Thank you, I've read through your page recommendation, but I want to stream a standalone Camera (RTSP-capable). Not the RPi's camera, so this is quite a different story. I'll try changing the port and get back to here.

Comment: Even after changing ports (now nginx is on 7080) it is the same. Not working. Any other tips?

Comment: @Daniel I only recommended the page for you for the Janus part of the configuration

Comment: I got mine working as a standalone Axis IP CAM with the Janus Demo room conference on Firefox, I dont know exactly where your problem is, I just gave instances of the issues I had to tweak when I got the white screen

Comment: Try using UV4L webrtc, it has pre-built in Janus Video rooms and Jitisi though experimental, its on Linux 32, 64, ARM. I dont know your OS

Comment: If you wana try that route let me know, because once you publish a room via the custom UV4L interface you can click a link that launches the demo room with your IP CAM both as a subscriber and publisher

Comment: and if you dont add @ with my name I dont get notifications on your post

Comment: you can also try @mpromonet https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102264/mpromonet custom demo room to at least test your browsers

Comment: @OlaB, thank you! Could you please send me the link with mpromonet's demo room? I can't seem to find it.