# Node.js, vs. Electron:: Run external command and show the stdout on interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to node.js and Electron and trying to run an external command in Electron and show the result with HTML.

I made an HTTP server-client version with node.js, which works fine.
But failed to make it to work with the Electron, even after following many answers here, such as

- [Node.js spawn child process and get terminal output live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live)
- [Piping data from child to parent in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946904/piping-data-from-child-to-parent-in-nodejs)

None of them worked for me for Electron.

### Node.js version works.

I'm showing my working node.js code as follows. This code, after running `node index.js`, and open `localhost:8888/start` in the browser, will show the output of `ls -al` on the webpage:

```js
// index.js

var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {};
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

The HTTP server:

```js
// server.js

var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

        route(handle, pathname, response);
}).listen(8888);

    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

The router that handles two requests, i.e., `start/upload`, differently:

```js
//router.js

function route(handle, pathname, response) {
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if (typeof handle[pathname] == 'function') {
        handle[pathname](response);
    } else {
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);

        // send an HTTP status and content-type in the HTTP response *header*
        // back to the browser that requested your server).
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        // send text in the HTTP response *body*.
        response.write("404 Not found");
        // finish the response.
        response.end();
    }
}

exports.route=route;
```

The actual request handlers:

```js
// requestHandlers.js

var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
    var content = "empty";

    exec("ls -al", 
        {timeout: 10000, maxBuffer: 20000*1024},
        function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            // send an HTTP status 200 and content-type in the HTTP response *header*
            // back to the browser that requested your server).
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

            // send text in the HTTP response *body*.
            response.write(stdout);

            // finish the response.
            response.end();
        });
}

function upload(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("You've uploaded data");
    response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

The above code worked for me in Safari.

### Electron version fails

Now I wanted to do the similar thing with Electron: Enter a command in an Entry box, run it through a submit button, and show the result on the same page below the controls. Here is my main process:

```js
// main.js

const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hello from Electron');
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile('./app/index.html');

    // mainWindow events, within app lifecycle
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', function() {
        console.log("Failed to load index.html");
    })

})
```

Now the renderer process:

```js
// renderer.js

const { shell } = require('electron');

const parser = new DOMParser();

const resultSection = document.querySelector('.results');
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
const newCmdForm = document.querySelector('.new-cmd-form');
const newCmd = document.querySelector('.new-external-cmd');
const newCmdSubmit = document.querySelector('.new-cmd-run');
const clearStorageButton = document.querySelector('.clear-results');

newLinkForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    const cmd = newCmd.value;
    processCmd(cmd);
});

const processCmd = (cmd) => {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec("ls -al", {timeout: 10000, maxBuffer: 20000*1024},
        function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            var out = stdout.toString();
            var result = 
                '<div class="text"' +
                `<h3>${out}</h3>` +
                '</div>';
            resultSection.innerHTML = result;
            console.log(result)
        });
}

const renderResults = () => {
    resultSection.innerHTML = '';
};

renderResults();
```

Here is the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cmdlet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<h1>Cmdlet</h1>
<div class="error-message"></div>
<section class="input-new-cmd">
    <form class="new-cmd-form">
        <input type="text" class="new-external-cmd" placeholder="default command" size="100" required>
        <input type="submit" class="new-cmd-run" value="Run">
    </form>
</section>
<section class="results"></section>
<section class="controls">
    <button class="clear-results">Clear</button>
</section>
<script>
    require('./renderer');
</script>

</html>
```

Knowing that the calling of external command is async, I put the renderer update code in the callback. However, this code shows `[object Object]` in the target area, instead of the output of `ls -al`.

Where was I wrong?

Comment: Well, since you also `console.log` the result, could you share what exactly is inside this object (`[object Object]`) that's displayed in your HTML?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner it's supposed to be `var out = stdout.toString();` so the stdout from the spawned child process.

Comment: Not sure what you get when doing `require('child_process')` in the renderer process...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// renderer.js

const { shell } = require('electron');

const parser = new DOMParser();

const resultSection = document.querySelector('.results');
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
const newCmdForm = document.querySelector('.new-cmd-form');
const newCmd = document.querySelector('.new-external-cmd');
const newCmdSubmit = document.querySelector('.new-cmd-run');
const newLinkForm = document.querySelector('.new-cmd-form');
const clearStorageButton = document.querySelector('.clear-results');

newLinkForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const cmd = newCmd.value;
    console.log(event)
    processCmd('cmd');
});

const processCmd = (cmd) => {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec("ls -al", {timeout: 10000, maxBuffer: 20000*1024},
        function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            var out = stdout.toString();
            const outArray = out.split('\n');

            let result = '<div class="text"'
            outArray.forEach(e => {
                result += `<h3>${e}</h3>`
            });
            result += '</div>';
            resultSection.innerHTML = result;
            console.log(result)
        });
}

const renderResults = () => {
    resultSection.innerHTML = '';
};

renderResults();
```

Try to use this. I added some changes at your **renderer.js**
This will be working well.

But I'd like to recommend to do these kind of operation at main process.
You know we can use IPC api to communicate between **Renderer** and **Main** process.

Have a look at this
https://www.christianengvall.se/main-and-renderer-process-in-electron/

But personally, I don't usually run `exec` at Renderer process. For this operation, I rather to use this such `exec` or `spawn` at main process.
We can use **IPC** to communicate between **Main** and **Renderer** process.

**IPCMain** is used for listening the events from the **Renderer** and it's available at only Main process. And **IPCRenderer** is used for sending the events from **Renderer** to **Main** process. So that.

Using IPCRenderer, You can send the event like this at **Renderer** process.

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

async function runCommand(cmd) {
  const res = await ipcRenderer.sendSync('runCommand', cmd);
  return res;
}
```

Then at Main process. (main.js)

```
// Listen runCommand event from the Renderer
// And return the result to Renderer.
ipcMain.on('runCommand', async (event, arg) => {
  event.returnValue = await runCommand(arg);
});
```

(you can declare the runCommand(arg) function yourself as your needs)
Feel free to use whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. `event.preventDefault()` and basically disabling the `renderLinks()` call are essential. I didn't realize that `renderer.js` is an update loop until now.

Comment: Thank you, the method provided is very useful. It worked once.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the node approach
2. Use [IPCRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) and [IPCMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) to poll/respond as to whether the command has completed
3. When IPCRenderer is told the content is ready, trigger an AJAX exchange to populate the renderer/website

PS: The documentation on how to use IPC in Electron seemed unclear to me -- and some of it seems not to work correctly! -- so if you need a simple & working example, here's [my app's startup splash](https://github.com/NathanHawks/FictionDB/blob/master/splash.html) and here's [the app code](https://github.com/NathanHawks/FictionDB/blob/master/app.js) that responds (see, mainly, lines 96-109 of the latter link).