# how do i stream a video from RTSP to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, rtsp

i'm using nodejs and react (both with typescript) and i'm trying to get the video from an IP Camera through RTSP,

i tried using **node-rtsp-stream** but this library uses **jsmpeg** as a consumer in the front-end and it does not work with react & typescript.

i need some recommandations or other solutions

Comment: you may review accepted ans -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011302/best-approach-to-get-rtsp-streaming-into-web-browser-from-ip-camera  AND consider a back-end piece to coordinate the stream for the react piece

Comment: i already tried to use the jsmpeg in my front-end code but i alway got type errors. Is there a way to use a readableStream after getting the stream from RTSP ?

Comment: well look at - https://www.npmjs.com/package/media-stream-player. seems appropiate to your components.  OR...  with a stream, if you need to u can look into wrappering the stream in a pipe . with a pipe , any of the players should work. they all accept piped input using the CLI "-" in place of input file

Comment: thanks, i'm going to try this one

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that we can transfer the RTSP to HTTP format(like HLS) first, then many of the video players and js libraries are able to play it.