# Best approach to stream RTSP IP Cam feed to React app and node.js express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, webrtc, rtsp

I am trying to build a set-up whereby I stream multiple IP Cam RTSP Video feeds to multiple users.
It needs to have minimal latency.

**Server Hardware**: Static IP Synology NAS
**Front-End**: React
**Back-End**: Node.js Express
**STUN/TURN server**: Coturn
**Video Feed**: Multiple IP Camera's RTSP feeds
**Video Encoder**: ffmpeg(?)
**Video Decoder**: ?
**Video Format**: ?
**Streaming Protocol**: WebRTC

I have every individual component up however am struggling with the part whereby I encode the RTSP feed.

What video format do I encode it to and how do I use WebRTC to stream to viewers on the front-end?

Comment: I was looking at this solution however it was during a time where WebRTC wasn't popular yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011302/best-approach-to-get-rtsp-streaming-into-web-browser-from-ip-camera

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77335988/17679565 the latency is about 260ms and there is a one click solution https://blog.ossrs.io/easily-stream-your-rtsp-ip-camera-to-youtube-twitch-or-facebook-c078db917149