# HTML5 video player for streams

Tags: html, video, vlc

There are other questions but they don't pretty much answer mine. I have a RPI stream command to send video to 192.168.1.xx:port (in my case I chose 192.168.1.39:8160). If I open a stream decoder like VLC and enter the web URL, the vide works just fine. This is OK, but I'd like to do a web version. How can I do so? Maybe use a common video tag and place that url in the src attribute? Or is there a plugin to insert in my HTML code for it to receive the web stream?

Thanks beforehand.

Note: my command is the following:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 800 -h 400 -fps 24 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:5258}' :demux=h264
```

Answer (score 0):

A video tag may just works in browsers that supports h264. If you'd like to have a wider support, you can use http://mediaelementjs.com/ that provides you a fallback to flash.

I'm used to use HTML5 video streamed over HTTP (partial request) and you have to check whether it's working with your streaming protocol. If not, you may have stream it using HTTP (or another way ?) 
You can test that by pasting the URI of the stream into a recent browser and see if the video is read.

Comment: and you sure this is able to open live video stream?

Comment: Lokk at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858936/html5-live-streaming

Comment: yep but im not using rtp, but http. _{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:5258}_