# Site or html page like youtube video directly from server

Tags: html, video, server, video-streaming

Ok i wanna do a simple question but i do not know if it comes also with a simple answer..
I will ask the simplest scenario that derives from this question... How can i "put" a video in a html page(site) from my pc or server that can be watched by everyone.
I dont want to embed a youtube video in the site but i want that video to be "embed" from my server or pc. What im actually asking is how to make a site like youtube(remove the part that users can upload videos) that has videos and are being "streamed"(i think thats the word) directly from youtube servers.

Answer (score 0):

Given your file tree looks like this :

```
index.html -- The web page you're serving
media/ 
media/bunny.mp4 -- Your video file
media/bunny.jpg -- [optional] A cover picture while the use plays the video.
```

And in index.html

```
<video src="media/bunny.mp4" width="400" height="222" controls poster="media/bunny.jpg"></video>
```

But if you're searching for an alternative where the user can't download the file (and that is a requirement even Youtube doesn't fulfil), you can read this post [HTML5 live streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858936/html5-live-streaming)
Or simply use a ready solution like [Plex Media Server](https://plex.tv/)