# how can i play VLC live streaming video in asp.net application using HTML video Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, vlc

I setup a live stream of the VLC Media player using Http and I want this stream to be played in my asp.net application using HTML 5 Video tag.

I expect to play the live stream of the VLC in my asp.net application.

Answer (score 2):

> First You need to supply the MIME type attribute in the video tag:
>   type="application/x-mpegURL". The video tag I use for a stream looks
>   like this.

```
<video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="VLCLiveStreamingURLGoesHere" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

Make sure to replace `VLCLiveStreamingURLGoesHere` with your VLC Live stream URL.

If you want to play direct HLS file, then add chrome extension called Native HLS Playback from chrome web app.

> A possible alternative for that:
>
> Use an encoder (e.g. VLC or FFmpeg) into packetize your input stream
>   to OGG format. For example, in this case I used VLC to packetize
>   screen capture device with this code:
>
> C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe -I dummy screen://
>   :screen-fps=16.000000 :screen-caching=100
>   :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,width=600,height=480,acodec=mp3}:http{mux=ogg,dst=127.0.0.1:8080/desktop.ogg}
>   :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
>
> Embed this code into a  tag in your HTML page like that:
>
> This should do the trick. However it's kind of poor performance and
>   AFAIK MP4 container type should have a better support among browsers
>   than OGG.

[HTML5 live streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858936/html5-live-streaming)