# html5 (Non-Live) True Streaming / VOD

Tags: html, video, streaming, rtsp

I understand you can feed the HTML5 <video> element RTP/RTSP video streams.
[[Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)

Great! Now how would one go about setting up the stream?

To be clear, I'm not looking to stream live video, just encode and stream existing media/video files. Think Flash Media Server (I have a working example of the Flash route already). I'm wondering how to approach setting up the streaming server backend to serve up all the right codecs for HTML5 video in all different browsers (H.264/Ogg/WebM)

I'm looking at maybe FFServer? Or possibly the new VOD feature for VLC for streaming in H.264 (Safari, Flash) over RTSP. Possibly Icecast server for the Ogg video? Is this even possible? Are there currently any working examples of this type of html5 VOD true streaming in the wild?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIVE555

Answer (score -1):

This is no answer, however I would suggest trying to solve one problem at a time.

Example:

Q: Can I stream from Flash Media Server via HTML 5 "video" tag?

A: No, but progressive download is possible. (Reference: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/855764)

Comment: I don't really want to serve HTML5 video from a Flash Media Server. I was using it as a real-world example of what I'm trying to accomplish. A better example would maybe be HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) created by Apple for streaming mp4 into HTML5, but this only works in the newest versions of Safari and iPhone/iPod and isn't a universal solution for streaming (no FF, Chrome, etc).