# html5 video chat

Tags: flash, html, video, chat

Is there ant tool or is html5 support realtime video streaming beetween users something like we can in flash. something like one to one video chat (skype) without installing any module for browser.

Can I do that with html5 or I need to use flash.

Any other soluton?

I have some html5 solutions but all need to be instaling some module.
What I want to do is: video chat one-one without install flash or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding one way video streaming: Here's another article I came across when I was wondering the same thing.

[Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)

It seems like HTML5 doesn't care, but there isn't likely too be much browser support. I suppose if you can transcode the stream to multiple formats simultaneously you could make it work one way

As for multi-direction, I've never heard of anything like that. This would require setting up a streaming server on the client PC, straight HTML wouldn't allow this.

Comment: I need some websocket transfer video beetwen users. something like ericsson labs do.

Comment: but what are you planning to use to serve video to that websocket?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific platform? ie. Windows where there may be a pre-installed service for this?

Comment: yes, specific platform, the best is?

Answer (score 1):

Try using WebRTC, it is very good for P2P connections.
I would recommend starting with http://simplewebrtc.com/ to see if its good for you and then search for suitable framework.

It is not supported by all browsers but can be used in latest Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Not supported in IE and Safari yet.