# Embeddable streaming video player that can play avi and asf cross-platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video-streaming

Is there an embeddable video player that can do the following:

1. Stream video from a server (It's saved to disk)
2. Run across browsers (or at least give the
   option for a fallback)
3. Run across mobile devices (Android and iOS)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into HTML5? video Embed, you should be able to stream from that. In terms of video protocol, you might have to make a converter but AVI might work. Give it a shot, I'd be interested to know what you find.

EDIT:

Links:

[Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)

http://www.pcworld.com/article/191030/how_to_ditch_flash_and_stream_video_with_html5.html