# HTML5 live "real-time" streaming audio (not from a file)

Tags: html, live-streaming

I've written a network "audio server" that streams audio data in real-time from a software-defined radio receiver.  Currently, the server acts as an RTSP server (as per [RFC2326](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt)) and the data is streamed over RTP (as per [RFC3550](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt)) when a client requests it via RTSP.

Currently, this requires a native application to act as the RTP receiver (e.g. VLC, gstreamer, etc.).  I'd like to be able to stream audio data to clients *without* requiring them to install a separate piece of software -- i.e. just load a webpage and the audio plays (maybe with a basic control UI displayed as well).

I've been out of the web development game for a while, but recently I've seen a lot of chatter about the new "streaming" `<audio>` tag in HTML5.  However, although it's called "streaming," it still seems to be file-oriented -- i.e. you have to have all the data on-hand a-priori.  So my question is:

**Is there a way to play "live" audio data (which is being generated in real-time) on a webpage using standard technologies/javascript libraries?  Ideally, it would work on both desktop and "mobile" platforms.**

It doesn't have to use the RTP transport under the hood -- I can rewrite or add new transports to the server if needed.  The goal is to avoid having any "special" native software on the client -- just load the webpage and the audio plays.

Comment: Just do a search for 'HTML5 RTSP.'

Comment: @Mooseman: I've searched for that many times before posting this -- the consensus seems to be "if you embed an rtsp:// link, the browser will open the native RTSP player."  My goal here is to not require a native RTSP player.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5