# How can I watch my video from a sdp file?

Tags: html, browser, ffmpeg, media-player, sdp

I'm using ffmpeg to create a streaming. It works fine. I have a server and with ffplay I can watch my stream.
My only (big) constraint is real time.

I have to embed it into an HTML page accessible from mobile devices.
I tried with HTML5 video tag but I can't include sdp files into it.

With ffmpeg I create a stream from my webcam. I have also created the sdp file but in HTML5 doesn't work.

The code is here:

**ffmpeg server:**

```
sudo ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -fflags no buffer rtp://224.10.20.30:20000
```

**file.sdp**

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 224.10.20.30
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 55.7.100
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:200
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=1
```

**ffplay: (It works)**

```
ffplay file.sdp
```

How can I view the stream in a browser?

Comment: Judging from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5 my guess is you'd need/want to stream it via some intermediate server: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide