# HTML5 video rtsp not working

Tags: html, video, streaming

I use this code:

```
<video src="rtsp://stream.tn.com.ar/live/tnhd1" controls></video>
```

Doesn't work. But in VLC media player *rtsp://stream.tn.com.ar/live/tnhd1* works!

**In localhost shows me:** Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

**Uploaded to a web server it shows me:**
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5?rq=1 ... in short, most browser don't (currently) support rtsp as a transport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, RTSP is **not** supported by most browsers, including "modern" ones. Even though it's protocol is in the W3C's HTML5 spec:

> User agents may support any video and audio codecs and container
>   formats.

Consequently, you would have to find a library or plugin written in JavaScript that would support it.

Comment: Ok. It doesn't work with RTSP, MMS, HTTP, RTMP. Which JavaScript library do you recommend me?

Comment: video.js is supposed to support it, still experimenting with this.