# iOS to browser live streaming

Tags: ios, live-streaming

I'm trying to capture a live stream from phone (iOS) and display it in a browser.

I've gotten the capturing working and I can see that about 2 second chunks of mp4 files get created on my server.

And here's where I'm stuck. What do I do from here to create a stream and display in a browser? There's a lot of good info regarding `ffmpeg` but I don't quite understand the flow. What do I do with these small mp4 files and create a stream? Can I use `<video>` tag?

I found this: [Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5?lq=1) and `rtp://myserver.com/path/to/stream` is mentioned in the answer. How do I create such a stream from those mp4 files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think the simplest solution for you could be using a media server, a good example is wowza streaming engine, with it you can easily ingest a live video with one of the supported encoding technologies (rtmp is a common and easily accessible example) and choose the output format(s) that you prefer, you can then use the appropriate format for playback in your browser or other devices

update: you can also use ffmpeg to capture an input and convert it to HLS, example command

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -y -threads 4 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128000 -ac 2 -s 640x360 -c:v libx264 -b:v 800000 -vprofile baseline -preset medium -x264opts level=31 -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_wrap 30 -start_number 1 output.m3u8
```

this will create an HLS stream that you can easily play on a browser

Comment: Wowza isn't free through, right? There has to be some solution using `ffmpeg concat` and/or `ffserver` from what I think. Apache also has modules for live streaming. Wowww sounds easy, but need a free solution. How does Twitch or other live streaming apps do, for example? What about using flv player? What can be done to flv files to live stream through flv player? Thanks!

Comment: i'm updating my answer with an example ffmpeg commands, i hope it helps

Comment: thanks, I'll try this out command, and update/accept accordingly.

Comment: so that `ffmpeg` command will create that output playlist file, but for live-stream, I have files that keep getting added to the INPUT. If I do have `<video src="....m3u8">` and even if I append new mp4 files to the playlist, browser won't know it, right? So, this is only half of solution.

Comment: I've been trying this using node.js `fs` `createReadStream`, and providing `start` and `end` options. Header is: `206`, `Content-Range: bytes start-end/total`. With my movie1.mp4, it works great! As the `<video>` reaches the end of buffered movie, it automatically requests the next chunk. The problem arises with multiple files: movie1.mp4, movie2.mp4, and so on. I don't know if it's possible, but once the range goes beyond movie1.mp4, I'm having movie2.mp4's data sent back. Having some problems here though. Thank you for your help.