# Realtime streaming video to HTML5 with RaspberryPi, gstreamer

Tags: html, video, raspberry-pi, streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to make a live stream from a Raspberry camera available on a HTML5 webpage.  Because of combination of factors, I would like to stream it to an outside server pc(Server pc os is window7) and this server should be able to supply the streams to the webpage HTML.

I'm able to get the stream from the Raspberry Pi and stream it with Gstreamer to an external server like this:

Raspberry Pi:

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -rot 270 -w 960 -h 720 -fps 30 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 - e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph24pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=External IP port=5000
```

External server

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

As a result I could display live video stream through gstreamer(GStreamer D3D video sink) in external server pc.

Now I have a problem:

I want to display this as HTML 5 video with Apache on server side (PC) instead of GStreamer D3D video output.

I searched for this solution for a long time but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: what about not using the gstreamer at all at server side and view the rtp stream with <video> tag like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)?

Comment: have you tried already?

Comment: I check your comment now , I changed way of streaming. I use gstreaming rtsp sever and connect rtsp sever through video player. but I want to study alternative way to streaming without gstreamer because gstreamer is so hard for me, I will refer your link and I will try this. really thanks!

Comment: gstreamer isnt so hard.. you just learn few things - like how to work with gst-launch and then its quite easy.. if you find something easier I wonder what that would be :) maybe ffmpeg?