# Stream raw h264 into web browser

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtp

So for the project, we already have a raw *h.264* stream that is correctly produce, but we want to send that into a web browser to be displayed as a simple live stream.

We are looking at RTP, because it seems like it can support such live stream. But it's all confusing.

So, is it possible to simply stream raw h.264 data into the web browser, using which ever protocol there is? That's all we want. We don't care about going rewinding or fast forward, just showing the last image produced, as fast as possible.

We might even be able to go with another encoder if it's possible and it's easily supported by browsers (*only Chrome really matters here*).

And the application is real time critical, so converting to m3u8/ts files is probably not a good solution because of the delay.

There's already a couple of discussion here about that, but it's so confusing and not even sure that's what we are looking for. Here are some that I found:
- [H264 RTP stream with gstreamer-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287334/h264-rtp-stream-with-gstreamer-1-0)
- [How to stream h264 with udp gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538695/how-to-stream-h264-with-udp-gstreamer)

Answer (score 0):

> So, is it possible to simply stream raw h.264 data into the web
>   browser, using which ever protocol there is?

No. Web browsers only supply HTTP, WebSocket, and WebRTC.

> And the application is real time critical, so converting to m3u8/ts
>   files is probably not a good solution because of the delay.

So Http is out. Leave you with WebRTC or fMp4 over web socket.

Comment: Okay, but do you know how to send h264 data over WebRTC or fMp4?