# ASP.NET dynamic RTSP live streaming in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, rtsp

I have a web application running ASP.NET MVC.

On my page I can add RTSP streaming URLs to a database, like

> rtsp://xx.xxx.x.xxx:xxx/MediaInput/h264

I need to display the live video stream on the webpage. VLC and quicktime plugins are no longer supported - so how do I convert this stream url to a HTML5 video or something similar, that all browsers can view?

Notice: I can't use 3rd party IP-cam streamers, because they require you to manually set up a URL. On my page, cams are added in run-time, so I need to programmatically export a live HTML video.

Comment: At this time getting rtsp streaming is not possible by HTML5. Look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5#1737065