# Videojs rtmp | doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-player, video.js, rtmp

Hi i tried everything im looking for solution 2h or smth but i cant find anything. So..
I got this error "No compatible source was found for this media." while using type="rtmp/mp4"

my code ..

```
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="1280" height="720" poster="1.jpg" data-setup="{}">
                      <source src="rtmp://goofly.tv/live/test" type='rtmp/mp4'>
                      <p class="vjs-no-js">
                        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                      </p>
                    </video>
```

Comment: RTMP is only supported in flash. Also rtmp/MP4 is not a thing. You can’t just make up mime types and expect the browser to play it. Finally, smth? If you are asking for other people to use their time to help you, spent the extra 2 seconds and type the whole word.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `HTTP` or `HTTPS` URL for streaming from RTMP.
You can use Wowza or any other streaming service provider, which can get you `http` or `https` urls which you can use in a html5 player.

Comment: can u give me an exmaple Sir ?.

Comment: And ya. I was using video.js like 3 months ago on the same server & domain then it was working perfectly but now i dunno whats happened.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5) SO questions and answers will be useful. Read all answers and all comments for each answer. Because all will give you a collective idea what you can do.

Comment: Never mind im using now the other player called "OSMF HLS Plugin" but ill anyways read them all, Thanks!