# Stream local IP camera to html via IP address w/o internet or server

Tags: html, video, stream, ip, ip-camera

My html coding is a bit rusty. Is it possible to code a very simple html page where I stream (2) IP cameras via a local network by using their static local IP addresses (no internet as this is for a remote construction site)?

I've tried every combination under the sun of the  the  tag with various error messages. But haven't been successful. 
I confirmed that the camera is actually accessible via my local network by typing the IP address into the browser. 
The end goal is to pull up my custom html page on a tablet where the operator can see both cameras. 
Below are code snippets that I've tried but none seem to work. I must be missing something. I feel like I'm close tho. 
The camera I'm testing with is a REOLINK IP camera. Here are the port values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR1zT.png)

or 

    
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.

Instead of the port 8080, I've tried other numbers also w/o luck. Am I attempting the impossible? 
Any help is appreciated. Please no reference to 3rd party services or web servers, etc as this application needs to run on a local network only (there is no internet available at the job site). 
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: what format is the stream coming from the camera? can you play the video by connecting from an app like VLC? This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5

Comment: The camera supports H.246 and RTSP, etc. I've made progress using an <iframe> tag. I'm able to bring up the camera's login page. However, I can't find a way to auto-login so that the operator doesn't have to type in credentials. I've searched stackoverflow and google of course for possible solutions and tried a couple java scripts without luck. 
An app like VLC wouldn't really help as we need to set this up very convenient for the machine operator. 
From the information I find, it sounds like HTML5, strangely does not natively support RTSP. So any help is appreciated. Thank you.