# Player for M2T streaming video in html

Tags: html, video, streaming

I need video player for play M2T format, streaming come from live camera, i need to show video from browser, now i can see it with VLC, any ideas?

Comment: you'll probably need to transcode from M2T to HLS or Dash. Depending on scenario VLC or ffmpeg may be sufficient, or you might need to use a service such as Azure Media Services

Comment: With HLS the browser can view it? now i have m2t file, it can be streamed from VLC for example but not browser.

Comment: m2t isn't supported by the HTML video element. VLC is a more general purpose video player. see https://caniuse.com/video for standard support. HLS/Dash can be consumed with various players such as Plyr.io

Comment: how i can convert m2t to hls? with ffmpeg is possible?

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985380/1569675, just replace your input (the `-i` parameter) as needed